# Getting Coordinates with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, location

In my iOS app, I have the following code. With this code I am hoping to get the **Latitude** and **Longitude** values of the device's current location.

**CODE AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        application.setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
        initializeLocationManager()
        return true
    }    

    func initializeLocationManager() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

**CODE ViewController**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

let localtionManager = appDelegate.locationManager

var currentLat = localtionManager.location.coordinate.latitude
var currentLng = localtionManager.location.coordinate.longitude

let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "\(currentLat),\(currentLng)", relativeToURL: baseURL)
```

On the third line of code in my ViewController from debugging I can see that the value returned is: `6.9530045620513319E-310`.

I have been told that this value can't be right, in other words something has gone wrong. Can you please tell me why this is wrong? and how I can get the latitude and longitude as strings so that I may pass them to a RESTful API?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `NSString` `format` method along with math functions as necessary to get the format you need. Write some code and if it does not work add it to your question.

Comment: BTW, the value provided is essential zero. Also you do not provide the format you need.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more code because "6.9530045620513319E-310." should not really be a valid value returned so you've probably made a mistake somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have updated the questions with more code and better context. Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`6.9530045620513319E-310` is not a valid value that should be returned for latitude or longitude, so you've most likely made an error somewhere else in your code. Without the rest of your code we can only make guesses as to what you did wrong.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    println(manager.location.coordinate.latitude)
    println(manager.location.coordinate.longitude)

    }
```

Try dropping this code into your CLLocationManagers delegate and if it doesn't output a valid latitude and longitude make sure that

- You have requested permission to have a users location and have added the reasoning into your info.plist
- You have called `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`while settings up your locationManager
- If you are using the simulator make sure you have gone to Debug-> Location and set a location

if it still doesn't work you're going to need to post more of your project code so we can figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: I have updated the questions with more code and better context. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription=true in the app's plist. That did it for me.